# How to move buffer list from bottom to top of UI?

Tags: buffers

When I invoke the buffer list (via: `:ls`), a selection window appears at the bottom of my UI. Is there a way to move this selection window to the top of my UI?

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: `:new | call setline(1, split(execute("ls"), "\n"))` xD

Comment: You can't, unless you rewrite substantial portions of Vim 's source code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Kedekai.  I am however looking to move the "selection window" for the buffer list (not the output of the file listing)  to the top of my screen. More generally, I would like to move the command input and status lines to the top of the screen.

Comment: (My suggestion was supposed to be a joke. And) There is no "selection window" of `:ls`. It _just_ prints the buffers and prompts user to press Enter.